# Поменять все вхождения стиля на другой

Tags: vba, ms-word, style

Есть список "легальных" стилей в документе. Надо все вхождения "нелегальных" стилей поменять на некоторый.
Вроде бы простой код, но не работает. В чём ошибка?

Private Sub replaceStyles()
    ' создаю массив допустимых стилей
    Dim validStyles() As String
    Dim strValidStyles As String
    strValidStyles = "*АННОТАЦИЯ*,*ЗАГОЛОВОК ЛИТЕРАТУРА*,*КЛЮЧЕВЫЕ СЛОВА*,*НАЗВАНИЕ СТАТЬИ*,*ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ*,*ПОДРАЗДЕЛ*,*РАЗДЕЛ*,*РИСУНОК И ТАБЛИЦА*,*СНОСКА*,*СПИСОК АВТОРОВ*"
    validStyles() = Split(strValidStyles, ",")

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim v As Integer

' по всем стилям в документе
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Styles.count
    ' если они используются
    If ActiveDocument.Styles(i).InUse Then
        valid = False
        ' соответствуют ли они легальным стилям
        For v = LBound(validStyles) To UBound(validStyles)
            If ActiveDocument.Styles(i).NameLocal = validStyles(v) Then
                valid = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next v
        ' если нет - меняем на "_ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ_" везде, где встретятся
        If valid = False Then
            With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = ""
                .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(i)
                .Replacement.Style = "_ОСНОВНОЙ ТЕКСТ_"
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: А если в каждую ветку if написать Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Styles?
Что в дебаге получится?

Comment: Не понял идею. Debug.Print печатать ActiveDocument.Styles отказывается - это массив из сотен стилей, большая часть которых не используется и содержимое которого от моих действий не меняется.
А если взять конкретный стиль - ActiveDocument.Styles(i) он внутри цикла тоже не меняется, остаётся прежним не зависимо от того, используется стиль или уже нет.